# Implementing pagenation in freemarker and getting error

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

getting freemarker error while creating pagenation :

the stacktrace is :

```
freemarker.template.TemplateException: Expected hash. data evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleSequence on line 68, column 15 in include/pagination.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:135)
    at freemarker.core.Dot._getAsTemplateModel(Dot.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.ComparisonExpression.isTrue(ComparisonExpression.java:111)
    at freemarker.core.ParentheticalExpression.isTrue(ParentheticalExpression.java:66)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:80)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Macro$Context.runMacro(Macro.java:172)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:603)
    at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:106)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

spring mvc code:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("#############************%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");

        List<RouteAddress> routeAddressList = new ArrayList<RouteAddress>();

        for(int i = 0;i<=100;i++){

            RouteAddress routeAddress = new RouteAddress();
            routeAddress.setAm_pm("am");
            routeAddress.setCity1("city1");
            routeAddress.setCity2("city2");
//          routeAddress.setDaysOfWeek("daysOfWeek");
            routeAddress.setEmail("email");
            routeAddress.setMobile(00000123);
            routeAddress.setName("name");
            routeAddress.setState1("state1");
            routeAddress.setState2("state2");
            routeAddress.setStreet11("street11");
            routeAddress.setStreet12("street12");
            routeAddress.setStreet21("street21");
            routeAddress.setStreet22("street22");
            routeAddress.setZip1("zip1");
            routeAddress.setZip2("zip2");
            routeAddress.setPageNumber(20);
            routeAddress.setPagesAvailable(true);
            routeAddress.setPageSize(10);
            routeAddress.setSortDirection("ascending");
            routeAddress.setSortField("city1");
            routeAddressList.add(routeAddress);

        }




        model.addAttribute(routeAddressList);
        return "address/searchroute";

    }
```

and here is the pagenation.ftl:

```
#if routeAddressList??>
    <#assign data = routeAddressList />
</#if>

<#--
 * Bind pagination data to the current data set these macros are using.
-->
<#macro bind routeAddressList>
    <#assign data = routeAddressList /> 
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the first page link
-->
<#macro first>
    <#if (data.pageNumber < 1)>   <#-- I am getting the error at this line -->
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.first", "« First" />
    </#local>
    <@page 0, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the last page link
-->
<#macro last>
    <#if (data.pageNumber >= data.pagesAvailable - 1)>
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.last", "Last »" />
    </#local>
    <@page data.pagesAvailable - 1, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the next page link
-->
<#macro next>
    <#if (data.pageNumber >= data.pagesAvailable - 1)>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber />
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber + 1 />
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.next", "Next »" />
    </#local>
    <@page pageNumber, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the previous page link
-->
<#macro previous>
    <#if (data.pageNumber < 1)>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber />
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber - 1 />
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.previous", "« Previous" />
    </#local>
    <@page pageNumber, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>
```

I have replaced my controller to :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/search")
public class SearchController extends AbstractController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model)
    {
        System.out.println("#############************%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");

        List<RouteAddress> routeAddressList = new ArrayList<RouteAddress>();
        PaginationData pagenationData = new PaginationData();

        for(int i = 0;i<=100;i++){

            RouteAddress routeAddress = new RouteAddress();
            routeAddress.setAm_pm("am");
            routeAddress.setCity1("city1");
            routeAddress.setCity2("city2");
//          routeAddress.setDaysOfWeek("daysOfWeek");
            routeAddress.setEmail("email");
            routeAddress.setMobile(00000123);
            routeAddress.setName("name");
            routeAddress.setState1("state1");
            routeAddress.setState2("state2");
            routeAddress.setStreet11("street11");
            routeAddress.setStreet12("street12");
            routeAddress.setStreet21("street21");
            routeAddress.setStreet22("street22");
            routeAddress.setZip1("zip1");
            routeAddress.setZip2("zip2");

            routeAddressList.add(routeAddress);


        }

        pagenationData.setRouteAddress(routeAddressList);
        pagenationData.setPageNumber(10);
        pagenationData.setPagesAvailable(true);
        pagenationData.setPageSize(3);
        pagenationData.setSortDirection("ascending");
        pagenationData.setSortField("city1");




        model.addAttribute(pagenationData);
        return "address/searchroute";

    }
```

and pagenation.ftl to :

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring/>

<#if paginationData??>
    <#assign data = paginationData />
</#if>

<#--
 * Bind pagination data to the current data set these macros are using.
-->
<#macro bind paginationData>
    <#assign data = paginationData />
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the first page link
-->
<#macro first>
    <#if (data.pageNumber < 1)>
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.first", "« First" />
    </#local>
    <@page 0, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the last page link
-->
<#macro last>
    <#if (data.pageNumber >= data.pagesAvailable - 1)>
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.last", "Last »" />
    </#local>
    <@page data.pagesAvailable - 1, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the next page link
-->
<#macro next>
    <#if (data.pageNumber >= data.pagesAvailable - 1)>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber />
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber + 1 />
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.next", "Next »" />
    </#local>
    <@page pageNumber, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the previous page link
-->
<#macro previous>
    <#if (data.pageNumber < 1)>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber />
        <#local classAttr = "class=\"disabled\"" />
    <#else>
        <#local pageNumber = data.pageNumber - 1 />
        <#local classAttr = "" />
    </#if>
    <#local text>
        <@spring.messageText "pagination.previous", "« Previous" />
    </#local>
    <@page pageNumber, text, classAttr/>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the page numbers and links
 *
 * @param maxPages (Optional) The maximum number of page links to show
 * @param separator (Optional) The seperator between page links
-->
<#macro numbers maxPages = 9 separator = " | ">
    <#local pagesBefore = (maxPages / 2)?floor />
    <#local pagesAfter = (maxPages / 2)?floor />
    <#if maxPages % 2 == 0>
        <#local pagesBefore = pagesBefore - 1 />
    </#if>
    <#local pageNumMin = data.pageNumber - pagesBefore />
    <#local pageNumMax = data.pageNumber + pagesBefore />
    <#if (pageNumMin < 0)>
        <#local pageNumMax = pageNumMax + (0 - pageNumMin) />
        <#local pageNumMin = 0 />
    </#if>
    <#if (pageNumMax >= data.pagesAvailable)>
        <#local pageNumMin = pageNumMin - (pageNumMax - data.pagesAvailable) />
        <#local pageNumMax = data.pagesAvailable - 1 />
        <#if (pageNumMin < 0)>
            <#local pageNumMin = 0 />
        </#if>
        <#if (pageNumMax < 0)>
            <#local pageNumMax = 0 />
        </#if>
    </#if>
    <#list pageNumMin..pageNumMax as pageNumber>
        <#if pageNumber == data.pageNumber>
            <#local classAttr = "class=\"selected\"" />
        <#else>
            <#local classAttr = "" />
        </#if>
        <@page pageNumber, "", classAttr/><#if pageNumber_has_next>${separator}</#if>
    </#list>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs a link to a specific page.
 *
 * @param pageNumber To page number ot link to
 * @param text (Optional) The link text (Defaults to page number if not set)
 * @param attributes (Optional) Any HTML attributes to add to the element
-->
<#macro page pageNumber text = "" attributes = "">
    <#if text == "">
        <#local text = (pageNumber + 1)?string />
    </#if>
    <#if (attributes != "" && attributes?starts_with(" ") == false)>
        <#local attributes = " " + attributes />
    </#if>
    <a href="?field=${data.sortField?url}&amp;page=${pageNumber}&amp;size=${data.pageSize}&amp;direction=${data.sortDirection?url}"${attributes}>${text?html}</a>
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs the current page number and the total pages
-->
<#macro counter>
    <#if data.pagesAvailable == 0>
        <#local pagesAvailable = 1 />
    <#else>
        <#local pagesAvailable = data.pagesAvailable />
    </#if>
    <@spring.messageArgsText "pagination.counter", [data.pageNumber + 1, pagesAvailable], "{0} of {1}" />
</#macro>

<#--
 * Outputs a link to sort by a field.

 * @param field The field to sort by. If field is different to the current sort field, the link will change the sort
 * field but not the sort direction. If the field is the same as the current sort field, the link will change the sort
 * direction.
 * @param text (Optional) The link text. If no text is specified the field name is used with a upper case first letter.
 * @param attributes (Optional) Any HTML attributes to add to the element
 * @param directions (Optional) An array of two items. The words being used in data.sortDirection to describe
 * the sorting direction of ascending or descending. Default: ["Asc", "Desc"]. So we can compare the current sorting
 * direction and switch to the converse.
-->
<#macro sort field text = "" attributes = "" directions = ["Asc", "Desc"]>
    <#if field == data.sortField>
        <#-- Change sort direction -->
        <#if data.sortDirection?lower_case == directions[0]?lower_case>
            <#local direction = directions[1] />
        <#else>
            <#local direction = directions[0] />
        </#if>
    <#else>
        <#-- Change sort field (leave sort direction) -->
        <#local direction = data.sortDirection />
    </#if>
    <#if text == "">
        <#local text = field?cap_first />
    </#if>
    <#if (attributes != "" && attributes?starts_with(" ") == false)>
        <#local attributes = " " + attributes />
    </#if>
    <a href="?field=${field?url}&amp;page=${data.pageNumber}&amp;size=${data.pageSize}&amp;direction=${direction?url}"${attributes}>${text?html}</a>
</#macro>
```

my error is gone but still I can't see any pagenation

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a `List<RouteAddress>`, yet you try to do things like `data.pageNumber` with it. Of course that can't work; you had to select a `RouteAddress` from the list first.

BTW, if you were using an up to date FreeMarker version, the error message would be more helpful. (Even for the those who try to help you, as it would quote the failing expression too.)